# Passing Query or Params to Google Auth routes

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, nestjs, authorization, google-oauth

the flow i want to implement is that first i will ask the user if he is a company or a candidate. when he choose one, then he will be shown relevant register forms. after then there will be buttons to signup with google.

when user click on signup with google. i want to get the **choice** he made lets say candidate in my backend.

and then i will make a user model with google provided info (email, name).
then i will redirect back to my app and show some fields which are required for registration.

I am using NESTJS as backend.

1. google.strategy.ts

```
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Strategy, VerifyCallback } from 'passport-google-oauth20';
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

config();

@Injectable()
export class GoogleStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'google') {
  constructor() {
    super({
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
      callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/google/callback',
      scope: ['email', 'profile'],
    });
  }
  async validate(
    accessToken: string,
    refreshToken: string,
    profile: any,
    done: VerifyCallback,
  ): Promise<any> {
    const { name, emails, photos } = profile;
    // console.log('profile', profile);
    const user = {
      email: emails[0].value,
      firstName: name.givenName,
      lastName: name.familyName,
      picture: photos[0].value,
      accessToken,
    };
    done(null, user);
  }
}
```

2. auth.controller.ts

```
@Controller('/api')

@Get('/auth/google')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('google'))
  async googleAuth(@Req() req: any) {
    console.log('req,,,', req.query.type);
  }

@Get('/auth/google/callback')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('google'))
  googleAuthCallback(@Req() req: any) {
    console.log('callback', req.query);
    return this.appService.googleLogin(req);
  }
```

3. app.service.ts

```
googleLogin(req: any) {
    if (!req.user) {
      return 'No user from google';
    }

    return {
      message: 'User information from google',
      user: req.user,
    };
  }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.